# Cannot see uploaded unit test results or code coverage report in IBM Cloud DevOps Insights Quality Dashboard

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops-insights

Using IBM Cloud CLI DevOps Insights plugin, I successfully uploaded my unit test results and code coverage report.

But in Quality Dashboard I only see my application name, and not the test result data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the CLI says test results were uploaded successfully, but only application name appears in Quality Dashboard,

- User might not have uploaded a build record
- The uploaded build record contains different `logicalappname` and `buildnumber` compared to test record's `logicalappname` and `buildnumber`

If user did not upload a build record, build records can be uploaded through the IBM Cloud CLI DevOps Insights plugin using this command:

`ibmcloud doi publishbuildrecord --logicalappname="$MY_APP_NAME" --buildnumber="$MY_BUILD_NUMBER" --branch="$GIT_BRANCH" --repositoryurl="$REPO_URL" --commitid="$COMMIT_ID" --status=pass`

Be sure to change the environment variables to fit the application information

Please note that `logicalappname` and `buildnumber` MUST be the same for both the uploaded build record and test records, so that test result data can appear in Quality Dashboard.

For documentation, please visit https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/DevOpsInsights